# What is 'it' in this sentence? (Need interpretation)

Tags: phrase-meaning, syntactic-analysis

> Where sign language was found among Native American tribes it was largely uniform.

I don't know what the real subject is in this statement and what *it* means here.
Why are *tribes* and *it*, both nouns, continuously written?
How can I interpret this sentence? Need your help. :)

Comment: What do *you* think the "it" refers to? And what does "continuously written" even mean? The question is unclear.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Erm, I imagine "continuously written" means written together without any intervening words. So that they aren't, discontinuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'It' refers to 'sign language' - there is nothing else in that sentence that it could refer to.

It often helps to turn a sentence around to get a better understanding:

> Where sign language was found among Native American tribes it was
>   largely uniform.
> Sign language was largely uniform where it was
>   found among Native American tribes.

Comment: Thank you! Now, I understand what the sentence means. :D